# Getting "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to append to nested list

Tags: python, list

This is part of my code which I wrote for my project. When I run that I got an error

> IndexError: list index out of range in python

```
s = "thisisTest"
m = list(s)
new_list = []
k = 0
d = 0
elemme = False

for i in m:
    if i.islower():
        elemme = True
        while elemme:
            k +=1
            new_list[k].append(i)
    elif i.isupper():
        elemme = False
        while elemme:
             k +=1
            new_list[k].append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Can someone explain what is a reason to that? I don't need new solution I need only explanation.

Comment: What's the goal of this code?

Comment: In the very first iteration, you try to access `new_list[1]` while `new_list` is empty. This raises the exception that you see.

Comment: Please put the line that it fails.But I think it probably is on `new_list[k][d].append(I)` You're creating a empty list in `new_list=[]`. Try to change the creation syntax to `new_list=[[] * k for i in range(d)]`.

Comment: Yes that was answer. Which I need. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to add values to a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975811/why-do-i-get-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-when-trying-to-add-values-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `new_list.append(i)` instead od `new_list[k].append(i)`.

Of course if `new_list` is list of list, then `new_list[k]` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`new_list` starts off empty. So anything that tries to access `new_list[k]` will always fail, no matter what the value of `k`.

You need to append things to `new_list` before you can start accessing its elements.

Answer (score 0):

first of all. you must use new_list.append(i).

then I didnt understand the goal of this code. I didnt  get what you re trying to do. In the code snippet:

```
> if i.islower():
>         elemme = True
>         while elemme:
>             k +=1
>             new_list.append(i)
```

you set ellemme to True and while is iterating while elemme is True (which is True always). So that will generate infinite loop and will give the memory error. On the other hand,

```
elemme = False
while elemme:
   k +=1
   new_list.append(i)
```

whats the need of while loop here where its obvious that elemme is false.