# Why do I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to add values to a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to put some data to my nested list.

```py
n_list = []
n = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):
    name = input()
    n_list[i].append(name)
    val = int(input())
    n_list[i].append(val)

print(n_list)
```

Comment: `n_list[i]` does not exist and `append` is a list method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're appending to list, you don't need to use index (by using `n_list[i]` you're pointing to i-th element of the array):

```
n_list = []
n = int(input())
for i in range (0,n):
    print(i)
    name = input()
    n_list.append(name)
    val = int(input())
    n_list.append(val)
print(n_list)
```

I you want to nest lists, do this:

```
n_list = []
n = int(input())
for i in range (0,n):
    print(i)
    inner_list = []
    name = input()
    inner_list.append(name)
    val = int(input())
    inner_list.append(val)
    n_list.append(inner_list)
print(n_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access the `i`-th item of **an empty** list. Since the list has 0 elements and you are asking for the `i`-th one, you get an error.

You could initialize a list with dummy values

```
n = int(input())
n_list = n * [None]
```

and then, write

```
n_list[i] = the_value
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is pretty simple and expected, so nothing to feel bad about.

```
The append function works in the following way (syntax):
    <list_name>.append(<item>)
```

is the name of the list and  is the item to be inserted.

In your code,

```
n_list[i].append(name)
```

You are trying to append to the list present in i th index of n_list, which doesn't exist. So its showing the error

Comment: thank for answer !! i have found solution from @Andronicius.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andronicus said you dont need to use the index [i]. But you are talking about a 'nested list'. What you are trying to do is not 'nested'. Seems like you want to create a list of key/value objects:

```
n_list = []
n = int(input())
for i in range (0,n):
    print(i)
    name = input()
    val = int(input())
    n_list.append([name, val])
print(n_list)
```

Results in something like: `[['myname', 2], ['yourname', 3]]`
or as a dictionary:

```
n_list = []
n = int(input())
for i in range (0,n):
    print(i)
    name = input()
    val = int(input())
    n_list.append({'name': name, 'value': val})
print(n_list)
```

Results in something like: `[{'name': 'myname', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'yourname', 'value': 4}]`

Answer (score 0):

This one is working.
the reasons why your method didn't work it's because you were
identifying an index that doesn't yet exist

```
n_list[i]
```

the list has no elements. that's why you need to append() the new ones.

```
n_list = []
n = int(input("write list length: \n"))
for i in range (n):
    item = [] #create the nested list for each loop

    name = input("Write name : \n")
    item.append(name)

    val = int(input("write value : \n"))
    item.append(val)

    n_list.append(item)

print(n_list)
```